# HTTPS redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess

My old domain is paradise-greece.com and I am forwarding to my new website paradisemykonos.com via Godaddy dashboard (301). Problem is, Google crawled https://www.paradise-greece.com/ which doesn't redirect, but using the http (unsecured) works fine. Search results are showing the secure https that doesn't seem to redirect to new website.

A solution might be to create a htacess to redirect the https to new domain, but I am not sure how to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume that you're using an URL forwarding service and those typically only work for plain HTTP, not for HTTPS. The canonical solution is to point your "old" domain to a webserver, frequently the same web server as where your new domain is hosted, with DNS records (`A`, `AAAA` or `CNAME` records) . On that webserver  you install a second minimal website, with a valid TLS certificate, for the old domain and then configure that website issue the necessary redirects yourself. That will also allow to direct specific old pages to new pages etc.

Comment: Is there any easier solution? Looks hard for me to do all that.

Comment: More or less the same is to (re-active) a managed web hosting plan for your old domain and then run permanent  redirects from there. I can of course be in the wrong, but I don't know of redirect services that will redirect https requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)